# On tkinter, how to determine which of buttons were clicked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a big tic-tac-toe game. Whenever a button is pressed, I want the class Gameplay to check whether there are amount n of same marks in a row (=win). I can't figure out how to tell to class Gameplay if method move() is activated in class Box.

Sorry, I'm just a starter. Here's my code.

```
from tkinter import *

# GRID MAXSIZE = 30*30


def game():
    n = [0]
    marks = ["X", "O"]
    points = [0,0]
    boxes = []


    class Box:
        def __init__(self, window, x, y):
            self.__x = x
            self.__y = y
            self.__state = ""
            self.__button = Button(window, text = self.__state, command = self.move, height = 1, width = 2)
        def move(self):
            if self.__state == "":
                self.__state = marks[n[0]]
                n[0] = (n[0]+1)%2
                self.__button.config(text = self.__state)

        def grid(self, **kwargs):
            self.__button.grid(**kwargs)
        def state(self):
            return self.__state

    class Gameplay:
        def __init__(self, size, towin):
            self.__mainwindow = Tk()
            self.__mainwindow.resizable(width=False, height=False)
            self.__mainlabel = Label(self.__mainwindow, text = "Se, joka saa " + str(towin) + " peräkkäin ensimmäisenä, voittaa!")
            self.__mainlabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = size)
            boxes = []
            for y in range(size):
                boxes.append([])
                for x in range(size):
                    boxes[y].append(Box(self.__mainwindow, x, y))
                    boxes[y][x].grid(row=y+1, column=x)
            self.__mainwindow.mainloop()





    playgame = Gameplay(20, 4)

game()
```

Comment: So exactly what is it that you want. When a button is pressed you want that button to return it's own value?

Comment: A usual way to achieve what you're attempting is to store the state of the game in memory, and modify it whenever an action happens. In your case, rather than checking what buttons were clicked, you should hold a 3x3 matrix (a list of lists), and change the value of the corresponding cell whenever a button is clicked. Then, performing checks on that matrix will be much easier than on the buttons.

Comment: You could also `bind()` the click event to call a method with a variable used to say what cell was click in. Should be super easy with `button_name.bind("<Button-1>", lambda: self.method(5))`. 5 could represent the middle of the grid if you go 123 for the top row and 456 for the 2nd row and so on.